# Device manager / Erase wrong device

Tags: factory-reset, android-device-manager

I went in to device manager and there were two devices that looked the same so I pinged them both one worked and the other came back inactive. I did and erase on it and then got an email saying my device would reset after restart it is the same device, somehow it was in device manager twice with two different model numbers. Is there a way to reverse this? I'm afraid I will lose everything if my device shuts down.  Someone please help me.